# xkb: Keymapping reverts backs with a Java App

Tags: java, minecraft, xmodmap, xkb

I am using a xkbcomp keyboard config for a second keyboard, but I am pretty sure it is reverting back to the default setup with java application. IE: Minecraft. Whenever I try to use the gamepad "the second keyboard," it outputs the default keys bypassing the configuration of xkbcomp even though the config works in the terminal after switching back to it. Is anyone familiar with this? Is there an alternative to xkbcomp or keymapping an individual keyboard?

[Terminal output of minecraft, xkbcomp, & java](https://pastebin.com/M0jud0Sq)